# Model Associations matching 2 Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, primary-key

2 Models => `Town` and `Island`

```
# Town.rb
belongs_to :player
belongs_to :island

# Island.rb
has_many :towns
```

The connection occurs via 2 different integer variables

```
:island_x 
:island_y

e.g. :island_x => 34 :island_y => 43
```

How can i set this association up ?

---

```
# CreateIslands
    create_table :islands, id: false do |t|
      t.primary_key :grepo_id
      t.integer :island_x
      t.integer :island_y
      t.integer :type_number
      t.integer :available_towns

      t.timestamps
    end

# CreateTowns
    create_table :towns, id: false do |t|
      t.primary_key :grepo_id
      t.integer :player_id
      t.string :name
      t.integer :island_x
      t.integer :island_y
      t.integer :slot
      t.integer :points

      t.timestamps
    end
```

Comment: You want set those as custom foreign keys?

Comment: I posted my answer.Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
Class Town < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :player
belongs_to :island ,foreign_key :island_x

end
```

**Update**

I see there is no use of `island_x` and `island_y` in both the `schemas`.You can just have a normal `foreign_key` `island_id` in the `towns` table and you can make a call `town.island` or `island.towns`.

**Update1**

I got it wrong with `foreignn_key` above.You can just make a method and make the matching like this

```
def some_method

@island_x = Island.find(params[:island_x])

@island_y = Island.find(params[:island_x])

@town_x = Town.where(:island_x => @island_x.id)

@town_y = Town.where(:island_y => @island_y.id)

end
```

Comment: the thing is that a lot of Towns have the same island_x value but not island_y. I need the exact match of x and y. Should i create a new variable containing joining those 2 and using that as the key ?

Comment: @The Mini John You want the towns that are matching with island_x and island_y?

Comment: Vice Versa. the connecting Keys are island_x and island_y. I need to can call town.island or island.towns.

Comment: @TheMiniJohn Ok.Show me the schema for island and town.Post it in the question.

Comment: The island_id is the :grepo_id in Islands which is also the primary_key. Those variables are pulled of a Game API, that's the variables i get. :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52424/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-pavan)

Comment: @TheMiniJohn I further updated as per our discussion in chat.